# Android: как по кнопке создать и выгрузить файл

Tags: android, файлы, upload

Есть апп, необходимо при нажатии кнопки: отдать пользователю. Отдать для того, чтобы передать на другой девайс, отправить предварительно записанный файл , например, по почте: как это сделать?

Comment: Больше конкретики в вопросе. Если файл уже записан на устройстве, зачем его отдавать? Куда отдавать?

Comment: Отдать для того, чтобы передать на другой девайс, отправить, например, по почте

Comment: Приложения на Андроид "фарят" между собой только URI, не сами файлы физически. К тому же URI могут быть не обязательно физические файлы. Так можно шарить и обьекты в облаке, контакты и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Создать `Intent` с действием `ACTION_SEND`, например (для текста):

```
private void setShareActionIntent(String text) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("text/plain");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
  shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
}
```

Это создаст штатное действие "расшарить", приложение для отправки (почта, мессенджер и т.д.) можно будет выбрать из установленных в системе.

Конкретно по файлам можно глянуть по ссылкам:
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing?hl=ru и 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985646/android-sharing-files-by-sending-them-via-email-or-other-apps

По `Intent` и `ACTION_SEND`:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=ru

Comment: спрашивали про файл а не про текст